# How to make a timer with UIDatePicker

Tags: ios, ios7, timer, uidatepicker

I'm trying to make a countdown timer with UIDatePicker set into Count Down Timer mode.

How do I extract the value from the UIDatePicker and turn it into a timer value, an integer to work with?

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please edit your question with more information.